# How do I improve the quality of my FFsplit Twitch stream?

Tags: streaming

I've recently changed the software I use to stream to Twitch from Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2 with ManyCam to just FFsplit. In doing a few test streams, viewers reported lag in the stream. In viewing the recorded stream on Twitch, the quality goes from perfect to a blurred chunky mess every few seconds. I started my first stream at 720p then took it down to 480p to see if there was any improvement and both had precisely the same results.

For my old setup I had downloaded a twitch preset which was set toinput at 640x480, a bitrate of 350Kbps and output size of 320x240. Audio was mono 44100Hz 64Kbps Mp3.

My current FFsplit config has the following settings:

Bitrate Mode CBR
Video Resolution 854x480
30 Fps
Video Bitrate 1800 kbps
Audio AAC
Bitrate 128
Channels Stero

The streams involve a screencast, webcam, and microphone. My speedtest also meets Twitch's requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue on my own. I hadn't realised my network cable was unplugged. This happened when I moved my computer and I never noticed since the WiFi immediately connected me to my network. When I returned to a wired setup, it cleared up the lag.